# Runing node server using "node server &"

Tags: linux, node.js

I have a problem when running my application Node.js. Use the command `"node server.js &"` to run my application in the background, however, when the application raises an exception the system falls. Any suggestion?

Thank you and sorry for my bad english

Comment: What does "the system fails" mean?  What exactly happens?  What exactly do you observe?

Comment: An uncaught exception will crash your program. Use `try {} catch (e) {}` to handle the exception and prevent the application terminating, or run the job with an init system https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: you solved my problem @Andy. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For small time debugging you could redirect stdout and stderr via pipes. Start with something like `node server.js 1> stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt &` , beware however that if you're printing a lot you might want to use some better logging functionality together with handling `uncaughtException` , see [node.js docs for uncaughtException](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception)

Comment: uncaughtException crash my program. Thats it! I see and solve the problem with try {} catch (e) {} exceptions. thanks